# Change value from flex in a TextField exported from Flash through a SWC

Tags: apache-flex, flash, textfield, swc

I created a MovieClip symbol in flash containing a dynamic TextField and a background. I exported it in a SWC(using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450925/export-swc-from-flash-and-access-child-from-flex) method) and I'm trying to use it from flex. When I try to change the default value of the text field the new value is not displayed(indeed the default value I put in flash is cleared on screen, but in the debugger it shows that the new value is set in the text field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the debugger indicates that the value is being set correctly, then perhaps the problem is that the textfield is unable to display it because of a missing font?

Check that you have correctly embedded the font in your SWC (check the Adobe docs [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f5f.html) for more info on embedding fonts).

Hope this helps...